# How to order two equivalent data frames with different row/column ordering to be the same? (With no variable names, R programming)

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is about R.

Suppose I have data frame `df1`:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
1  10  1  9  2  1
2   7 10  7  3 10
3   6  5 10  2  2
4   4  9  8 10  5
5  10 10  7  8  8
6   8  1  4 10  3
7   9 10  7  8  2
8   4 10  9  6  4
9   6  9  3  2  7
10  2  4  2  9  9
```

and data frame `df2`:

```
    B  E  C  A  D
1   4  9  2  2  9
2   9  7  3  6  2
3   1  3  4  8 10
4  10  8  7 10  8
5  10  2  7  9  8
6  10 10  7  7  3
7   9  5  8  4 10
8   1  1  9 10  2
9  10  4  9  4  6
10  5  2 10  6  2
```

And suppose I don't have the column names for each field. The data frames are equivalent except for the row/column ordering (they contain the same information)

Is it possible to order the two data frames without knowing their column names to be the exact same in terms of where the values are? How can I order the data frames based on their values so they are exactly identical/have the exact same format?

i.e. how can I get both data frames to look like: (note that this is just `df1`)

```
  +----+----+----+----+----+
  | 10 |  1 |  9 |  2 |  1 |
  |  7 | 10 |  7 |  3 | 10 |
  |  6 |  5 | 10 |  2 |  2 |
  |  4 |  9 |  8 | 10 |  5 |
  | 10 | 10 |  7 |  8 |  8 |
  |  8 |  1 |  4 | 10 |  3 |
  |  9 | 10 |  7 |  8 |  2 |
  |  4 | 10 |  9 |  6 |  4 |
  |  6 |  9 |  3 |  2 |  7 |
  |  2 |  4 |  2 |  9 |  9 |
  +----+----+----+----+----+
```

Thanks!

**Data** in `dput` format.

```
df1 <-
structure(list(A = c(10, 7, 6, 4, 10, 8, 9, 4, 6, 2), B = c(1, 
10, 5, 9, 10, 1, 10, 10, 9, 4), C = c(9, 7, 10, 8, 7, 4, 7, 9, 
3, 2), D = c(2, 3, 2, 10, 8, 10, 8, 6, 2, 9), E = c(1, 10, 2, 
5, 8, 3, 2, 4, 7, 9)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")


df2 <-
structure(list(B = c(4, 9, 1, 10, 10, 10, 9, 1, 10, 5), E = c(9, 
7, 3, 8, 2, 10, 5, 1, 4, 2), C = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 
10), A = c(2, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 4, 10, 4, 6), D = c(9, 2, 10, 8, 
8, 3, 10, 2, 6, 2)), .Names = c("B", "E", "C", "A", "D"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you want df2 to be exactly the same as df1, why don't you just copy df1?

Comment: You can sort each column and compare them from one dataframe to another. When you find sorted columns that matches, you can the associate each column name of `df2` with a column name of `df1`. And then do the same with the lines

Comment: why tag pandas here ?

Comment: @ZiGaelle @Len but suppose I don't have both data frames at the same time. I would like a way to sort the data frames so they match without having `df1` for example. I'm using this for random forest imputation. I need to be able to get the same results when using either `df1` or `df2` as my source - as I am using this for random forest imputation which depends on randomness. Would this be even possible?

Comment: @Wen Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem, all you have to know is that `order` is its own inverse.

```
ordFun <- function(x, y){
  i1 <- order(x)
  i2 <- order(y)
  y[i2][order(i1)]
}


result <- lapply(names(df1), function(nm) ordFun(df1[[nm]], df2[[nm]]))
result <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, result)
names(result) <- names(df1)

result
#    A  B  C  D  E
#1  10  1  9  2  1
#2   7 10  7  3 10
#3   6  5 10  2  2
#4   4  9  8 10  5
#5  10 10  7  8  8
#6   8  1  4 10  3
#7   9 10  7  8  2
#8   4 10  9  6  4
#9   6  9  3  2  7
#10  2  4  2  9  9
```

Comment: But suppose I don't have both data frames at the same time. I would like a way to sort the data frames so they match without having `df1` for example. The reason is that I'm using this for random forest imputation. I need to be able to get the same results when using either `df1` or `df2` as my source - as I am using this for random forest imputation which depends on randomness. Would this be even possible?

Comment: @Grint You *"would like a way to sort the data frames so they match without having `df1`"*? How is that possible? Please note the verb *to match*... What you could do is to produce a vector of indexes based on, say, `df1` and then match/sort the other df's as they become available.

Comment: @Grint if you had the columns in the same order, you could always sort whatever data frame `df` you get with something like `df[do.call(order, as.list(df)),]`, but if the order of your columns also changes, you'd have a harder time finding a solution because you'd have to check all (?) column permutations.